# Issue with apriori rules in r - missing lhs products

Tags: r, associations, apriori, arules

I am following the instructions from https://www.r-bloggers.com/implementing-apriori-algorithm-in-r/ to generate association rules but I am unable to generate lhs products in my rules. I guess it is because my transactions cannot be broken down.

Here is a sample of what my raw csv data looks like:

```
  itemList
1 ContentManagement
2 Migration,Explorer
3 Explorer,Migration
4 Explorer,ContentManagement
5 Migration,Explorer
```

Then, I apply the following:

```
#load package required
library(arules)

#convert csv file to basket format
txn = read.transactions(
  file = "ItemList.csv",
  rm.duplicates = TRUE,
  format = "basket",
  sep = ",",
  col = 1
);
inspect(txn)

#remove quotes from transactions
txn@itemInfo$labels <- gsub("\"","",,txn@itemInfo$labels)
```

The transactions look like this:

```
[1] {ContentManagement}            1
[2] {Migration,Explorer}           2
[3] {Explorer,Migration}           3
[4] {Explorer,ContentManagement}   4
[5] {Migration,Explorer}           5
```

When I apply the following:

```
#run apriori algorithm
basket_rules <-
  apriori(txn,
          parameter = list(
            minlen = 1,
            sup = 0.01,
            conf = 0.01,
            target = "rules",
            maxtime=10
          ))
#basket_rules <- apriori(txn,parameter = list(sup = 0.00001, conf = 0.01, target="rules"),appearance = list(lhs = "Migration")))

#view rules
inspect(basket_rules)
```

It gives the disappointing results, which is the following:

```
     lhs    rhs                                    support    confidence lift
[1]  {}  => {ContentManagement}                    0.01175068 0.01175068 1   
[2]  {}  => {Migration, Explorer}                  0.01226158 0.01226158 1   
[3]  {}  => {Explorer,Migration}                   0.02145777 0.02145777 1
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how your file is structured. It is not a comma separated file because there is a space and not a number between the line number (row label) and the items which are separated by a comma. Remove the line number leaving only the items and set `col = NULL` in `read.transactions`.

If you wrote your file with R then make sure that you use `row.names = FALSE` in `write.csv`.

Comment: Hi, thanks @michael for the tip, it helps a little bit (the title is not part of the analysis which is good) but it does not split the transaction into distinct products... :(